# How to check if two events are pointing to the same procedure in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, events

Say I have a Button1.OnClick event linked to Button1Click procedure. I also have Button2.OnClick linked to some other procedure. How do I check that both events are linked to different or same procedure from runtime?

I tried to test if:

- Button1.OnClick = Button2.OnClick, but that gave me an error (Not enough actual parameters)
- @(Button1.OnClick) = @(Button2.OnClick), error again (Not enough actual parameters)

How do I test it properly?

Comment: See [Delphi: Test event handler assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24108773/576719) for a generic solution.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A method reference can be broken down in to two parts, the pointer to the object and the pointer to the method itself. There is a convenient record type defined in the `System` unit called `TMethod` that allows us to do that break down.

With that knowledge, we can write something like this:

```
function SameMethod(AMethod1, AMethod2: TNotifyEvent): boolean;
begin
  result := (TMethod(AMethod1).Code = TMethod(AMethod2).Code) 
            and (TMethod(AMethod1).Data = TMethod(AMethod2).Data);   
end;
```

Hope this helps. :)

**Edit**: Just to lay out in a better format the problem I am trying to solve here (as alluded to in the comments).

If you have two forms, both instantiated from the same base class:

```
Form1 := TMyForm.Create(nil);
Form2 := TMyForm.Create(nil);
```

and you assign the same method from those forms to the two buttons:

```
Button1.OnClick := Form1.ButtonClick;
Button2.OnClick := Form2.ButtonClick;
```

And compare the two `OnClick` properties, you will find that the `Code` is the same, but the `Data` is different. That is because it's the same method, but on two different instantiations of the class...

Now, if you had two methods on the same object:

```
Form1 := TMyForm.Create(nil);

Button1.OnClick := Form1.ButtonClick1;
Button2.OnClick := Form1.ButtonClick2;
```

Then their `Data` will be the same, but their `Code` will be different.

Comment: Can I use Addr(AMethod1) = Addr(AMethod2) as well?

Comment: `Addr()` is the same as `@` and just gives you the `Code` part of the method.

Comment: Under which circumstances pointers to Code may be the same and pointers to Data not?

Comment: If you have two objects instantiated from the same class, they will have the same Code pointers, but different Data pointers.

Comment: Indeed. My answer already shows that misassumption in much less code. :)

Comment: Hmmm... I wouldn't say that... The two buttons are not the problem, it's what the two buttons' OnClick properties are pointing to that is... If you had two form objects instantiated from the same class (eg `Form1 := TMyForm.Create(nil); Form2 := TMyForm.Create(nil);`) and then assign a method on each of them to the buttons OnClick handlers (eg `Button1.OnClick := Form1.ButtonClick; Button2.OnClick := Form2.ButtonClick;`), then their `Code` will be the same but their `Data` will be different.

Comment: Yes of course. Data points to the object instance of the event handler implementation, not the instance of the object that exposes the event property.

Comment: I have to ask: I work mostly with legacy Delphi 7 systems where testing "@MyObject.SomeEvent = @MyEventHandler" worked just fine. Why doesn't Delphi allow it anymore?

Answer (score 22):

I do it with this function:

```
function MethodPointersEqual(const MethodPointer1, MethodPointer2): Boolean;
var
  Method1: System.TMethod absolute MethodPointer1;
  Method2: System.TMethod absolute MethodPointer2;
begin
  Result := (Method1.Code=Method2.Code) and (Method1.Data=Method2.Data)
end;
```

It works, but if someone knows a less *hacky* way to do it then I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: +1 I didn't take the Data into account, but you probably need that too. I don't know of a better way to do it either.

Comment: But this is still the second best solution. The very best solution is not to write code that needs this check at all. :)

Comment: hacky here is abusage of `absolute` keyword with `^Untyped` parameters, look below, Nat presented the same expression in Pascal.

Comment: Yes i do not :-D It is not appropriate here!

Comment: no, it is not equivalent at all, it dodges typecast rules which **can** be respected here

Comment: @David Heffernan, problem is not what other function does not work with arbitrary, problem is what your function accepts arbitrary data, assumes 8 bytes and returns result of this UB. Meanwhile, OP wants event methods, which can be achieved with overloads and maybe inilining.

Comment: @David Heffernan, and what you are offering?

Comment: @David Heffernan, i only see your demands, how about my compensation?

Comment: @David Heffernan, a) upvote is not valuable enough, b) usually you do an opposite. Try again.

Comment: Sorry, moral satisfaction motive waned when i faced demands and ad hominem. Enough petty challenges (seriously, my dog keep doing that when i have food on my hands, be superior!)

Comment: +1 Liked it a lot. And works with any method pointer signature. Don't know if it can be done with generics (but I don't believe it's possible)...:-)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question...but here's my 2cents...

This is answer is similar to Nat's but doesn't limit us to only TNotifyEvents...and answers David's question of how to do this with out it being a hack...

```
function CompareMethods(aMethod1, aMethod2: TMethod): boolean;
begin
  Result := (aMethod1.Code = aMethod2.Code) and
            (aMethod1.Data = aMethod2.Data);
end;
```

I use it like so

```
procedure TDefaultLoop.RemoveObserver(aObserver: TObject; aEvent: TNotifyEvent);
var
  a_Index: integer;
begin
  for a_Index := 0 to FNotifyList.Count - 1 do
    if Assigned(FNotifyList[a_Index]) and
     (TNotify(FNotifyList[a_Index]).Observer = aObserver) and
      CompareMethods(TMethod(TNotify(FNotifyList[a_Index]).Event), TMethod(aEvent))     then
begin
  FNotifyList.Delete(a_Index);
  FNotifyList[a_Index] := nil;
end;
```

Also a quick and dirty demonstration

```
procedure TForm53.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a_Event1, a_Event2: TMethod;
begin
  if Sender is TButton then
  begin
     a_Event1 := TMethod(Button1.OnClick);
     a_Event2 := TMethod(Button2.OnClick);
    if CompareMethods(TMethod(TButton(Sender).OnClick), a_Event1) then
       ShowMessage('Button1Click Same Method');
    if CompareMethods(TMethod(TButton(Sender).OnClick), a_Event2) then
       ShowMessage('Button2Click Same Method');
  end;
end;


procedure TForm53.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a_Event1, a_Event2: TMethod;
begin
  if Sender is TButton then
  begin
     a_Event1 := TMethod(Button1.OnClick);
     a_Event2 := TMethod(Button2.OnClick);
    if CompareMethods(TMethod(TButton(Sender).OnClick), a_Event1) then
       ShowMessage('Button1Click Same Method');
    if CompareMethods(TMethod(TButton(Sender).OnClick), a_Event2) then
       ShowMessage('Button2Click Same Method');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It still has a type cast which is what annoys me about any solution.

Comment: Yes, but it's the very thing that I was trying to avoid. So your sentence where you refer to my answer isn't right. In fact your version is even more annoying to use because you replace one type cast in the callee with one at the sire of every call. Not a huge irritation but still hacky.

Comment: To me, it's just like inheritance typecasting... there are times where it has to be done...Since every method of an object is based on TMethod it's a minor hack.

Comment: Right, but you aren't avoiding the hack as you claim. What I'd like would be for every of object type to be compatible with TMethod.