# Someone managed to install InstantObjects in Delphi XE4?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, instantobjects

Someone managed to install InstantObjects in Delphi XE4?

I'm compiling the latest sources who are on svn repository. After correcting some issues as the compiler version, I am stuck in the following code snippet:

```
procedure TInstantAccessor.SetOnCompare(Value: TInstantCompareObjectsEvent);
begin
   if @Value <> @FOnCompare then
   begin
      FOnCompare := Value;
      RefreshView;
   end;
end;
```

Resulting in the error message "[dcc32 Error] InstantPresentation.pas (1580): E2008 Incompatible types" on the line:

```
if @Value <> @FOnCompare then
```

But they are the same type: *TInstantCompareObjectsEvent*

What's wrong?

Comment: Could this be a bug of Delphi XE4?

Comment: @TLama, the comparison is testing if the same function is being assigned again. If not using `@`, the compiler won't compile because it would expect the functions to be called. Flavio, have you double checked the {T} compiler directive? More info here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29

Comment: I think the code is comparing whether objects occupy the same memory address...

Comment: @TLama: no problem, happens with everyone. ;-)

Comment: @FabricioAraujo, you meant {$T}?

Comment: Exactly, sorry for the typo.

Comment: I´ve set in dpk source as {$T+} but don´t worked...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe casting the procedural pointer to the generic `Pointer` type can solve:

```
procedure TInstantAccessor.SetOnCompare(Value: TInstantCompareObjectsEvent);
var 
  PValue, PFOnCompare: Pointer;
begin
   PValue := Pointer(@Value);           // Casting the original pointer to an generic pointer 
   PFOnCompare := Pointer(@FOnCompare);
   if @PValue <> @PFOnCompare then
   begin
      FOnCompare := Value;
      RefreshView;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: I'd say [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6896442/960757) might be helpful. Of course only if the intention of the comparision here is not to just compare the `Code` part of the method (what using of the `@` operator at method comparision does). In such case the code like `if TMethod(Value).Code <> TMethod(FOnCompare).Code then` should work.

Answer (score 0):

What Fabricio wrote in the comments make sense. I surrounded the code with the directives {$T-} and {$T+} and the code compiled!

Now I'm in trouble in other parts of the code, but that's another story.

```
procedure TInstantAccessor.SetOnCompare(Value: TInstantCompareObjectsEvent);
begin
{$T-}
   if @Value <> @FOnCompare then
   begin
      FOnCompare := Value;
      RefreshView;
   end;
{$T+}
end;
```

Thank you all.

Comment: So the comparison was intended to be between untyped pointers and `@` operator (for some reason) was generating typed pointers...