# Delphi: Test event handler assignment

Tags: delphi, event-handling

I want to assign an event handler in constructor, if it does not have one assigned. Consequentially I want to remove the eventually assigned event handler in destructor. I wrote the code as follows, but cannot be compiled.

```
constructor TSomeControl.Create(Panel: TPanel);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FPanel := Panel;
  if not Assigned(FPanel.OnResize) then
    FPanel.OnResize := HandlePanelResize;
end;

destructor TSomeControl.Destroy;
begin
  if @FPanel.OnResize = @HandlePanelResize then // [dcc32 Error] E2036 Variable required
    FPanel.OnResize := nil;
  FPanel := nil;
  inherited;
end;
```

How to test it properly? I know a solution is to use a variable to record, whether I have assigned `OnResize`. But I do not want this as solution.

Comment: See [How to check if two events are pointing to the same procedure in Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6896155/576719).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No need to write any custom code here as you can use the already existing comparers from `Generics.Defaults`:

```
destructor TSomeControl.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FPanel) and TEqualityComparer<TNotifyEvent>.Default.Equals(
    FPanel.OnResize, HandlePanelResize) then
    FPanel.OnResize := nil;
  FPanel := nil;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: The `TEqualityComparer` also works with `Event<T>`, code like below will work as well: 
`function TForm1.Button1OnClickIsMultiCast: Boolean;
begin
  Result := TEqualityComparer<TNotifyEvent>.Default.Equals(
    Button1.OnClick, FMultiCastEvents);
end;`

Comment: @EdwinYip That is because `Event<T>` has an implicit operator to `T` ;)

Answer (score 7):

This is complicated by the fact that `OnResize` is a property rather than a variable. And it's quite hard to refer to a method directly without the compiler thinking you want to call the method. This is the big drawback of Pascal's convenience of allowing you to call a procedure without using parens.

All this makes it rather hard to do it in a one-liner. As far as I can see you will need to do something like this:

```
destructor TSomeControl.Destroy;
var
  Method1, Method2: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  if Assigned(FPanel) then
  begin
    Method1 := FPanel.OnResize;
    Method2 := HandlePanelResize;
    if TMethod(Method1) = TMethod(Method2) then
      FPanel.OnResize := nil;
  end;
  FPanel := nil;
  inherited;
end;
```

This relies on modern Delphi's `TMethod` record which includes an overloaded equality operator to make the `=` test work.

I would wrap this all up in a generic method if I was doing it more than once. It might look like this:

```
type
  TEventComparer = class
    class function Equal<T>(const lhs, rhs: T): Boolean; static;
  end;

class function TEventComparer.Equal<T>(const lhs, rhs: T): Boolean;
begin
  Assert(SizeOf(T)=SizeOf(TMethod));
  Result := TMethod((@lhs)^)=TMethod((@rhs)^);
end;
```

You'd call it like this:

```
destructor TSomeControl.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FPanel) and TEventComparer.Equal<TNotifyEvent>(FPanel.OnResize, 
    HandlePanelResize) then
    FPanel.OnResize := nil;
  FPanel := nil;
  inherited;
end;
```

One thing that this highlights is that the generic constraints available to you do not allow you to constraint a type to being a method pointer. Hence the basic sanity check that the size of `T` is the same as the size of a method. This doesn't offer much safety though. You can call this method passing `Int64`, or `Double`. I'd be interested to see if anyone can come up with a cleaner variant.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. I'm avaricious to know, if the code can be written as some generic helper function? The method type might not be limited to `TNotifyEvent`. I tried by myself, but the compiler complains about `TMethod(Method1) = TMethod(Method2)` when I wrap it as a generic helper function.

Comment: Great skill. My mistake was to use `lhs` not `(@lhs)^`.

Comment: Something like: `var p: PTypeInfo; begin p := TypeInfo(T);
  Assert(p.Kind = tkMethod);`

Comment: @StefanGlienke Yup, that's quite nice. Especially now that Emba fixed the bugs in their method comparers!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As the solution of Stefan is more native, I accept his answer. I hope you will agree.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The comparers always worked because it was coded as explicit comparison of Code and Data pointer. What did not work was direct comparison of two TMethod variables iirc.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 Yes, I agree. I upvoted Stefan's answer. I have in the past shied away from these comparers because of some bugs but they do work in the very latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `Generics.Defaults` or any generics at all. There is `TMethod` record declared in `System` unit, so this is probably the simplest one:

```
destructor TSomeControl.Destroy;
var
  Event: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  Event := HandlePanelResize;
  if TMethod(FPanel.OnResize).Code = Addr(Event) then
    FPanel.OnResize := nil;
  FPanel := nil;
  inherited;
end;
```