# Version dependent compiles - $ENDIF and $IFEND

Tags: delphi

I seem to be in a catch 22 situation. I want to add compiler version dependant code. OK - that is pretty standard. But the syntax of the $IF statements is different between versions.

Here is what I am trying to achieve

```
{$IF CompilerVersion = 28}
  if (fPendingObject = pObject) and (Addr(fPendingActionEvent) = Addr(pPendingActionEvent) ) then
{$ELSE}
  if (fPendingObject = pObject) and (@fPendingActionEvent = @pPendingActionEvent ) then
{$ENDIF}
```

This compiles in Delphi XE7, but not in Seattle or Berlin. Those compilers require the syntax

```
{$IF CompilerVersion = 28}
  if (fPendingObject = pObject) and (Addr(fPendingActionEvent) = Addr(pPendingActionEvent) ) then
{$ELSE}
  if (fPendingObject = pObject) and (@fPendingActionEvent = @pPendingActionEvent ) then
{$IFEND}
```

($IFEND instead of $ENDIF). But XE7 won't accept that syntax.

There obviously must be a trick, [and indeed the Delphi 2009 documentation says so](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirsifenddirective_xml.html), but my poor brain can't work out the trick. Can someone help?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that code to need conditional compilation in the first place. They're syntactically equivalent, and the whole idea is better expressed using techniques described in [discussions of how to compare method pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6896155/33732) (assuming the objects on the left are the targets of the respective method pointers on the right).

Comment: No, you wouldn't think so. I didn't either - until I tried it. wrt to your comparing pointers link, thank you, but it is not appropriate to my need, where the type of reference is not known. For example it could be a TButton.OnClick event, or a TEdit.OnChange event, or indeed something completely different.

Comment: The types shouldn't matter. Answers by David and House demonstrate comparing method pointers in a type-neutral manner. An answer on a linked question includes a generic solution, too.

Comment: The answer by David I agree is type neutral - but is quite hacky and is not obvious. The House result extends David's idea in a less hacky way but is no more obvious. I don't see how either method is better or more maintainable than a single line (albeit under a conditional compile, necessitated by differences in the compilers which even you agree shouldn't be there). I am not saying that either method is bad - they both show an in depth knowledge that clearly exceeds mine.

Comment: I would just say that replacing a single line of code with a function just to defeat limitations of a compiler is not necessarily better than what I have.

Comment: Anyway - I think all of this is off topic to the question.

Comment: @Dsm - if the linked answers are not obvious for you, then your code is probably wrong; generally you can't compare event handlers as you do.

Comment: @user246408. Why not? It is not a trite remark - I am genuinely curious. At the end of the day I thought both methods point a code section - one directly and one via the v-tables, but direct or indirect I thought that they were equivalent. Of course I know that event handlers can be changed. but that is not relevant to what I am doing. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Dsm - you are wrong, there are no v-tables at all here. Read the linked articles - a method pointer is actually 2 pointers, and comparing method pointers is comparing both pointers.

Comment: @user246408. Yes, I was wrong to mention v-tables. But the underlying sentiment remains. And I did read the linked articles!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a compiler option that allows the use of the older `{$IFEND}` directive:

- Project

  - Options

    - Delphi Options
    - Compiling

      - Require $IF to be terminated by $IFEND: [x] true

Then there is the `{$LEGACYIFEND ON|OFF}` directive, which does the same, locally. Setting it on will make XE7 accept `{$IFEND}`, like in the older versions. I often use something like:

```
// For Delphi XE3 and up:
{$IF CompilerVersion >= 24.0 }
  {$LEGACYIFEND ON}
{$IFEND}
```

Obviously, this option is on by default in your Seattle or Berlin projects, but not in XE7. You can turn it off or on, depending on your preferences.

Comment: More info in: docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Legacy_IFEND_(Delphi)